# brms: how do I setup a model with multiple categorical variables, so that all levels are present and none are baked into the general intercept?

Tags: categorical-data, brms

brms: how do I setup a model with multiple categorical variables, so that all levels are present and none are baked into the general intercept?

E.g. suppose we have predictors:

- gender (2 levels)
- educ (educational level, 3 levels)

Doing

```
brm(somey ~ 0 + gender)
```

seems to allow me to have both levels of gender present as coefficients. However, if I modify this to:

```
brm(somey ~ 0 + gender + educ)
```

leads to still having the 2 genders individually, **but now one level of *educ* is baked into the intercept**. **I'm not sure if this is desirable. The intercept will have the base value of any variable, but again I am not sure if it's useful.** I wonder how to have all 3 levels individually present and none baked into intercept.

Doing

```
brm(somey ~ 0 + gender + 0 + educ)
```

does not help.

---

Or put otherwise:

Can I have the model:

```
\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2
```

rather than

```
\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do - could you be looking for the interaction between gender and educ, i.e. the intercept computed each combination of gender and educ?

Comment: @atmo It's also possible that I'm misapplying the Bayesian models in the sense that maybe all the levels are not meant to be baked into the intercept. OTOH, this may make inferring the models more difficult. With 1 multilevel variable it's easy since one know what's baked into the intercept. But with > 1 multilevel variables the intercept becomes confusing.

Comment: I don't think I can help you beyond referring to Gelmans book: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/